# Getting error while executing R code "Cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'"

Tags: r, shiny

```
require(shiny)
setwd("C://Users//Harshad//Desktop//Equiskill - BA")
cars <- read.table(file = "cars.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, quote="")

var_list <- as.character(names(cars))


ui <- fluidPage
(
  selectInput(inputId = "var",label = "Select Dependent Variable:",choices =    c(var_list))
)

server <- function(input,output)
{
}

shinyApp(ui <- ui, server <- server)
```

I am getting error "ERROR: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'" while executing above shiny app code in R studio. Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid putting `newlines` and even `spaces` after the function names. Refer to [style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) or [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml). Code below works perfectly fine.

```
require(shiny)
# load your data I am using default mtcars data here
cars <- mtcars

var_list <- as.character(names(cars))

ui <- fluidPage(
        selectInput(inputId = "var",label = "Select Dependent Variable:", choices = c(var_list))
    )

server <- function(input,output)
{
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error, with no error line number.
But I don't think I have a spacing problem:

`server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    req(infile)
    return(read.csv(infile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$separator))
  })
  
  output$colnames <- renderUI({
    df <- filedata()
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectcol", choices=(df[100, ]))
  })
}`

It occurs only after i load the file...
Edit: didn't know there was no code formatting in comments..

Comment: R doesn't care about newlines and spaces. The problem with the original code is that it does an odd assignment in the call to `shinyApp()`. Instead of `shinyApp(ui <- ui, server<-server)`, the correct code is `shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)`